# strlen to int c++ - Why can't I do this?

Tags: c++, casting

Where is this code wrong?
It won't let me cast `strlen(s)` into an `int` that I can iterate it until `i` is equal to the length of the string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

   string s;
   cin >> s;

   for (int i = 0; int n = (int)strlen(s); i < n, i++)
   {
      cout << s[i] << endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: use `s.size()` `strlen` is for `char` array strings.

Comment: Do I have to change the header file?

Comment: You only have to `#include <string>` and `#include <iostream>`

Comment: I think the underlying problem is that you don't know C++ well enough.

Comment: I just started learning, so fair enough.

Comment: If you're learning C++ from a good source (such as a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465)), I would expect that source to teach you about `std::string` and its member functions *long before* the first mention of `strlen` and similar C-legacy stuff. If they're teaching you C++ by starting with C, *they're doing it wrong.*

Comment: It wouldn't let me use < ... >

Comment: I'm learning CS50 online, but it's a different language than C++, and I'm forced to  use C++ with no background on the language, because I can't run a virtual computer on my laptop.

Comment: Then you might want to also follow a C++ learning source (such as one of the books I linked to) to learn C++ (assuming you want to learn it, that is).

Comment: @LouisGermanotta `and I'm forced to use C++ with no background on the language, because I can't run a virtual computer on my laptop` Sorry that makes no sense at all. Why would you need a VM in order to learn the language ?

Comment: Because I have to turn my work in that way. It's stupid. but thanks for your advice

Comment: @LouisGermanotta The start of CS50 seems to focus on C, using its own type named "string". Doing the course in C++ if it teaches C will only complicate things. (It honestly doesn't seem like a very good course.)

Comment: I mean C is used mostly at Apple to make games and stuff, and eventually that's what I want to do .

Comment: @LouisGermanotta No, it isn't. Very few games or other applications are made in C these days, particularly at Apple (they don't make any games at all).  (You are aware that C and C++ are different languages, right?) CS50 seems more geared towards web development than games.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not that the result of `strlen` can't be cast to an `int`, but that `strlen` can't be used with `std::string`.

`strlen` is for "C strings", zero-terminated arrays of characters.

`std::string` has a `size` member function:

```
int main()
{
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << s[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

There is nothing inside the C header `<string.h>` that applies to `std::string`.
A [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) can be useful.

Comment: It should be `size_t i`, if you want to compile without warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Because `strlen` expects to get a `char const*` as it's argument. You should probably use `s.size()` instead as `s` is a `std::string`.

In addition you should probably not compute `strlen` inside a loop like that due to performance issues (`s.size` on the other hand should be able to complete in O(1) time so it would be OK).

Then there's a few other problems with your program, already at line one. You can't include a file by using `#include //iostream`, you should use `#include <iostream>` instead.

Second you cannot declare a variable in the condition of a for loop as you try to do, and you probably shouldn't assign instead of comparing (one equal sign is **not** the same as two). You should have written `for( int i = 0; i != s.size(); i++ )`

Third you shouldn't do the check in the update expression in the `for` construct. What goes there will only be evaluate to update the loop variables and such and the truth value will be disregarded.

Overall I think you should pick up an introduction to C++ book or find a good tutorial online. Your code simply has to much problems to conclude that you have learnt even the most basic C++.

Comment: I'm learning CS50, not C++. I'm being forced to learn the way CS50 works by doing it in C++, because I am unable to run virtual computers, but thanks.

Comment: The // ....// was because it didn't look like it would show #include <iostream> in the post

Comment: @LouisGermanotta In that case it looks like you have to learn C++ as part or prerequisite of the course, at least the basics...

Answer (score 0):

[`strlen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) is for `char` arrays.

[`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) has a member function called [`size`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/size/) and [`length`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/length/).

If you still want to use strlen, you can call [`c_str`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) and pass the returned string to [`strlen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/).

```
std::size_t length = s.size();
for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
```

You can also iterate over the elements of the [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/):

```
for (std::string::iterator itr = s.begin(); itr != s.end(); ++itr)
{
    std::cout << *itr << std::endl;
}
```